# How to Schedule a Pentaho job using Control M?

Tags: pentaho-data-integration, control-m

I have a Pentaho(kjb) which needs to be scheduled through Control-M, can someone help in this regard?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? People go on week long courses to learn how to use Control-M, it’s not something that can be taught in one answer.

Comment: I worked with Control-m, but it is used to schedule Informatica Jobs with the help of PMCMD command, but not sure which command is used to schedule Pentaho jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Try Control-M application integrator , you can define custom type job using it .
as question is on liner i dont have much insight of what function you want to trigger , However recently i worked on BluePrism type job integration in Control--M using it.

also if your product support API you can integrate using web-service module of Control-M job type or can directly call using any script/program to schedule via Control-M .

Check below link for various available App integrator type job already created by Community .

https://communities.bmc.com/groups/control-m-application-hub/content

Regards,
Mani